# Disable `object_name_linter` in lintr

Tags: r, configuration, lint

I want to introduce [`lintr`](https://github.com/jimhester/lintr) to our projects. Unfortunately our variable naming can be improved and we've actually decided to have CamelCase for functions and camelCase for variables. This makes `lintr` very unhappy, I've tried to disable the linter using `with_defaults(object_name_linter = NULL)` but I'm not succeeding. I successfully disable other linters using technique.

How can I disable (or allow multiple styles) for the `object_name_linter` in `lintr` through `.lintrc`?

I'm on version 1.0.3, if I run with

```
lint(fileName, 
     with_defaults(camel_case_linter = NULL, snake_case_linter = NULL
))
```

it seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found my issue, I looked at the source code on GitHub and figured that I needed to set

`object_name_linter = NULL`

In 1.0.3 `object_name_linter` doesn't seem to be implemented yet and

`camel_case_linter = NULL, snake_case_linter = NULL`

does the trick.